Trying to offset camera position in material function
I am working on a camera occlusion mask for my top-down shooter game. The camera is not directly over the player, but instead is at about a 45 degree angle behind the player. In creating my occlusion mask, I got the mask to appear directly below the camera, but since the player is in front of the camera a bit the occlusion occurs behind him (so you can't see the character).
I am trying to figure out how, in the material function, I can offset the 'camera position' node to account for the distance away from the player. (The distance is static and never changes)
Could somebody please offer me some tips on how I can offset the camera position in the function, so that it occludes above the player correctly?
Thanks!
I have provided a couple of screenshots to show my material function, and what the current camera-view looks like.


